# Computation in R

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, machine-learning, computational-mathematics, machine-precision

I am trying to find the following expression for $n=50, m=40$ in the software R.

\begin{equation}
m \binom{n}{m} \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{ \binom{m-1}{i}(-1)^i }{n-m+1+i}
\end{equation}
Ideally this expression should be evaluated to be 1 (in fact this expression  gives value 1 for all $m <n$ and that can be proved theoretically). But instead it is giving  166254.90890021951. I understand it is precision problem. How do i get over it ?

Comment: Oh yes !. (-1)^i is there. I have made the changes. Thanks.

Comment: can you show us your code ? ... R is a dreadful language & will do all kinds of crazy things & not warn you about it ! ... I have this working in c# ... maybe the answer is that I give you that ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit ...Here is the R code 

n<-50

m<-40

a<-0

for(i in 0:(m-1))

{

  a<-a+choose((m-1),i)*(-1)^i*(1/(n-m+1+i))

}

a<-a*m*choose(n,m)

a

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate this directly as written, you'll need arbitrary precision via a library in R.

```
f <- function(n,m) {
  require(gmp)
  i <- 0:(m-1)
  m*as.bigq(chooseZ(n,m)) * sum(chooseZ(m-1, i)*(-1)^i / (n-m+1+i))
}

f(50,40)
# Big Rational ('bigq') :
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks @A.Webb. This works well. However this is a part of my actual expression. I have an expression which I am writing in three different parts sum of which gives me the original one. Since this lacks space over here I am writing in three different parts in three consecutive comments. The tuning parameters are as $n=40, m=35, T=1.5, \theta_1=1, x=6$.

Comment: The first part is 

$  {k\binom{n}{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\binom{k-1}{i}(-1)^i}{(n-k+1+i)}e^{-\frac{\tau}{\theta_1}(n-k+1+i)}pgamma(x-\frac{\tau}{k}(n-k+1+i);k,\frac{k}{\theta_1})}$

Comment: The second part is 

$ \sum_{i=k}^{m-1}\sum_{s=0}^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{s}(-1)^s e^{-\frac{\tau}{\theta_1} (n-i+s)} pgamma(x-\frac{T}{i}(n-i+s);i,\frac{i}{\theta_1}) $

Comment: The third part is 

$ m \binom{n}{m} \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\binom{m-1}{i}(-1)^i}{n-m+1+i} [pgamma(x;m,\frac{m}{\theta_1})-e^{-\frac{\tau}{\theta_1}(n-m+1+i)}\times \\
pgamma(x-\frac{\tau}{m}(n-m+1+i),m,\frac{m}{\theta_1})]$

Comment: Here pgamma(x-a;b,c) is disribution function of shifted gamma random variable (shifted by a, and parameters are b,c). At $x=6$ sum of the above three terms should give value close to 1. I tried your method. But somehow its not working. Could you please find your valuable time and do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find arbitrary precision functions for gamma in the `Rmpfr` package of R.

Comment: You should also check out `sumBinomMpfr` from the same package, which is for calculating alternating binomial sums. Also, look for opportunities to simplify the expressions first, to avoid having to calculate unnecessary precision.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
n = 50;  m = 40;  k = m*choose(n,m);  i = 0:(m-1)
k*sum(choose(m-1, i)*(-1)^i/(n- m + 1 + i))
## -16608.58
```

There may be issues of computational stability because
$k =  410,891,126,800$ and the sum computes to $-4.042088e-08.$

Trying the computation for smaller values of $n$ and $m$, all seems OK.

```
n = 5; m = 4; k =m*choose(n,m);  i = 0:(m-1)
k*sum(choose(m-1, i)*(-1)^i/(n-m+1 + i))
## 1

n = 10; m = 8; k =m*choose(n,m);  i = 0:(m-1)
k*sum(choose(m-1, i)*(-1)^i/(n-m+1 + i))
## 1
```

So you seem to be at (or over) the edge of overflow for the case with $n = 50, m = 40.$

Try using logs for the constant $k$ and for each term in the sum (exponentiating before summing).
For example, you could use `lchoose` for parts of the computation:

```
choose(50, 40)
## 10272278170
lchoose(50, 40)
## 23.05271
exp(lchoose(50,40))
## 10272278170
```

*Note:* I do not share @Donald's reservations about R. However, in any computation
in any computer language, you need to realize that you are not dealing with all the real numbers; you
are dealing with a huge, but finite set of the rationals. Consequently you need to be aware of possibility of overflow and underflow in intermediate steps. 
This is especially true when dealing with factorials, binomial coefficients,
Gamma functions, and exponentials.

Comment: Yes...it gives correct values for small values of n,m. How do I take care of other values since values like n=50 or m=40 are very much required in my case study which I am doing.

Comment: Method with logs should work for values like 40, 50. // Maybe start a separate question, explaining combinatorial background, and asking if there's a way to simplify the expression. // Even a quick look shows many large factors to be cancelled in ${n \choose m}{m-1 \choose i}.$ Maybe even enough to avoid the need to use logs.

Comment: Still it is not working. It would be great if you can come up with a solution. I must appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Please try suggestion in @A.Webb's (+1) Comment. Otherwise, show me the simplified form, per my last Comment, you have tried. Did you try approach using logs?